# How to use Color with rememberSaveable in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, colors, android-jetpack-compose

I want to keep color after screen rotation. But this code throws an error:

```
var color by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(Color.Red) }
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MutableState containing Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1) cannot be saved using the current SaveableStateRegistry. The default implementation only supports types which can be stored inside the Bundle. Please consider implementing a custom Saver for this class and pass it as a stateSaver parameter to rememberSaveable().
```

How to implement `Saver` for `Color`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1: use custom `MapSaver`**

```
val ColorSaver = run {
    val redKey = "Red"
    val greenKey = "Green"
    val blueKey = "Blue"
    mapSaver(
        save = { mapOf(redKey to it.red, greenKey to it.green, blueKey to it.blue) },
        restore = {
            Color(
                red = it[redKey] as Float,
                green = it[greenKey] as Float,
                blue = it[blueKey] as Float
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Example of use:

```
var color by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = ColorSaver) { mutableStateOf(Color.Red) }
```

Read more in official documentation: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#mapsaver

**Solution 2: store data state in ViewModel**

A simpler and more universal solution: you can just move all variables with complex data that are not supported by `rememberSaveable` into the ViewModel.